# How to speed down or delay file_get_contents PHP to scrape a fully loaded page?

Tags: php, html, web-scraping

I'm using `file_get_contents` + regular expressions to scrape data from a website.

I'm using the function inside a "for" loop to scrape all pages from 1 to 2000.

The website I'm trying to scrape is coded in `React` I guess, because I see things like this in its html: `data-reactid="408"`

My code works well to scrape data from the first page only, but when it goes to second page and later pages, it returns different html tags to what I'm expecting and thus my regular expressions return 0 element found.
After investigating a little, I discovered that `file_get_contents` is very fast to the point it returns a version of the page not fully loaded, I think `React` does some post-modifications to HTML href links and transforms **span** tags to **a** tags.

Now I'm looking for a way to tell `file_get_contents` to wait until the page is in it's final loaded state, and then return me the HTML.

Do you have an idea of doing so ?

Comment: You cannot do it like this, any method of getting HTML without interpreting the javascript may miss things which are done on page load (or later).  I would also recommend not using regex and look at something like DOM Document to read pages,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP (and `file_get_contents`) only fetches the html code, it will not execute any client-side JavaScript and because of that it will not reflect any dynamic changes to the website.

For that, you would have to use something like [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) or [CasperJS](https://www.casperjs.org/). These can do client-side rendering on your side and return you the final html code.

Comment: thank you for your suggestions, i'll try to read about puppeteer and casperJS.

Answer (score 0):

The default value for a timeout in file_get_contents() is 60 seconds, that seems pretty long and you did not specify how long was the page to process.

If it is more than 60 seconds, you can use :

```
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 90);
```

to ask for more, for instance 90 seconds.

If the pages loads faster than 60 seconds, then I guess the problem is in your code logic, like you expect some client side Javascript to be run.